# Accepted socket connection from /hostname:55306 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I have configured the Kafka cluster,Storm cluster and Hadoop cluster. every thing works fine when their are no jobs.

When I submit the storm jar (which gets data from kafka and process ,then store it into  Hdfs)  in standalone mode ,it works fine

After configuring it to server properties same code and run it on server it gives following error:

```
[2018-07-03 12:54:00,370] INFO Accepted socket connection from /192.168.3.222:55306 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2018-07-03 12:54:00,381] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.3.222:55306 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-07-03 12:54:00,383] INFO Established session 0x3645ed69ca40031 with negotiated timeout 20000 for client /192.168.3.222:55306 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-07-03 12:54:02,429] WARN caught end of stream exception (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)

EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x3645ed69ca40031, likely client has closed socket
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:239)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[2018-07-03 12:54:02,433] INFO Closed socket connection for client /192.168.3.222:55306 which had sessionid 0x3645ed69ca40031 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2018-07-03 12:54:06,000] INFO Expiring session 0x1645ed69c8c0041, timeout of 20000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2018-07-03 12:54:06,000] INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1645ed69c8c0041 
(org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

Respective versions I am using:

- apache-storm-1.0.6
- kafka_2.11-1.0.1
- zookeeper-3.4.12
- hadoop-2.9.1

***nimbus log***

```
2018-07-04 12:28:54.455 o.a.s.d.nimbus timer [INFO] Setting new assignment for topology id test-topology-1-1530686803: #org.apache.storm.daemon.common.Assignment{:master-code-dir "/usr/local/apache-services/data/storm", :node->host {"7c98bf5a-38d5-4a13-95ad-966be3a51c49" "datanode2.sakha.com"}, :executor->node+port {[2 2] ["7c98bf5a-38d5-4a13-95ad-966be3a51c49" 6700], [1 1] ["7c98bf5a-38d5-4a13-95ad-966be3a51c49" 6700], [3 3] ["7c98bf5a-38d5-4a13-95ad-966be3a51c49" 6700]}, :executor->start-time-secs {[1 1] 1530687534, [2 2] 1530687534, [3 3] 1530687534}, :worker->resources {["7c98bf5a-38d5-4a13-95ad-966be3a51c49" 6700] [0.0 0.0 0.0]}, :owner "hduser"}
2018-07-04 12:28:54.520 o.a.s.d.nimbus pool-14-thread-7 [INFO] Created download session for test-topology-1-1530686803-stormjar.jar with id a9762861-224e-4f40-824b-ae0efa687452
```

***supervisor log***

```
2018-07-04 12:30:46.461 o.a.s.d.s.Container SLOT_6700 [INFO] Creating symlinks for worker-id: b9c3daa0-4f4d-42d7-9963-e93b6e6179a3 storm-id: test-topology-1-1530686803 for files(0): []
2018-07-04 12:30:46.461 o.a.s.d.s.Container SLOT_6700 [INFO] Topology jar for worker-id: b9c3daa0-4f4d-42d7-9963-e93b6e6179a3 storm-id: test-topology-1-1530686803 does not contain re sources directory /usr/local/apache-services/data/storm/supervisor/stormdist/test-topology-1-1530686803/resources.
2018-07-04 12:30:46.461 o.a.s.d.s.BasicContainer SLOT_6700 [INFO] Launching worker with assignment LocalAssignment(topology_id:test-topology-1-1530686803, executors:[ExecutorInfo(task_start:2, task_end:2), ExecutorInfo(task_start:1, task_end:1), ExecutorInfo(task_start:3, task_end:3)], resources:WorkerResources(mem_on_heap:0.0, mem_off_heap:0.0, cpu:0.0), owner:hduser) for this supervisor 7c98bf5a-38d5-4a13-95ad-966be3a51c49 on port 6700 with id b9c3daa0-4f4d-42d7-9963-e93b6e6179a3
```

Comment: I would take a look at the worker log (path depends on the Storm version, so please post which version you're on). There's likely more useful information in there. Consider checking the Nimbus and Supervisor logs as well.

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing I have added the details you needed

Comment: The worker log should be in your-storm-directory/logs/worker-artifacts/your-topology-id/your-worker-port-number/worker.log. Please try looking in those files, there's probably going to be some error logging in there.

Comment: as you said if look in worker log i found :java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil.hasKerberosTicket ,even after adding hadoop auth jar @StigRohdeDøssing

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your dependency tree. You posted that you got `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil.hasKerberosTicket` in your worker log. This points to you having the wrong Hadoop jar versions on your classpath when you submit the jar, or maybe you're missing the jars entirely.

Here's the pom for storm-hdfs https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.0.6/external/storm-hdfs/pom.xml. By default, it compiles against Hadoop 2.6.1. If you want to use another Hadoop version, you need to ensure that you replace the listed Hadoop dependencies with newer ones in your pom (i.e. you need to manually list e.g `hadoop-client` in version 2.9.1 in your pom).

A good tool for you to debug this is to run `mvn dependency:tree` in your project, that'll let you know which versions of which jars you are including in your build.

Comment: what  i have done is ,I have manually added required jars in to storm lib path(because if you run  jar in storm cluster  ,it take libraries from strom lib path) or else is their any other options too run on storm cluster @Sting Rohde Dossing

Comment: yeah even i have tried with the dependencies what you have given still i find same error :https://stackoverflow.com/q/51187185/7527189 @Stig Rohde Dossing