# Not found :org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am running storm jar in a cluster ,where I configured hadoop,kafka,storm  cluster

when I run the jar in local mode it works fine ,when I run it on storm cluster, I am finding respective error in Storm UI:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil.hasKerberosTicket(Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<init>(UserGroupInformation.java:666) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:861) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:820)
```

***pom.xml***

[Click here to view POM file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Jl_Nx-xUJtUnuNg4-IGcc1MWVUgq3mD_)

After some google I found I found we have add hadoop auth jar.even after i finding same error

Comment: How do you build the jar with job?

Comment: I have built  jar using maven ,but i have included all jar in storm lib and then submitted it to cluster. @AlexOtt

Comment: see https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter, especially the part about fat jar

Comment: Yeah ,I have done the same  @AlexOtt

Comment: Please post your project POM. I suspect you're packing the Hadoop dependencies into your fat jar as well, and those versions are likely too old.

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing I have added my pom

Answer (score 4):

I think you're packaging an old Hadoop jar.

Take a look at the storm-hdfs POM https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.0.6/external/storm-hdfs/pom.xml. When you use the Shade plugin, the jar you end up with will contain all your dependencies, including transitive ones brought in through direct dependencies. Storm-hdfs declares a dependency on a list of Hadoop jars. You need to make sure that you're declaring the same list of Hadoop jars in your POM if you want to use a different version of Hadoop from the default.

Specifically what's happening is that you haven't declared hadoop-auth in your POM, so your POM gets packaged with the default version of that jar (2.6.1). Since that version of hadoop-auth is incompatible with the other Hadoop jars (which are 2.9.1), you get an exception at runtime.

You should either exclude all Hadoop jars from your import of storm-hdfs and then put the jars you want to use in Storm's lib directory, or add the right versions of the Hadoop jars to your dependency list in your POM.

Edit:
I think I found your issue. You haven't set the scope of storm-core to provided. Since storm-core depends on hadoop-auth, and you haven't declared it explicitly, Maven will try to guess which version of hadoop-auth you need based on where the dependency appears in the tree. Since hadoop-auth appears as 2.9.1 through some of your Hadoop dependencies, but 2.6.1 through storm-core, you happen to get 2.6.1 put in your jar.

If you want to avoid this kind of thing in the future, you should use Maven's dependencyManagement block https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management.

i.e. you should add something like the following to your pom, and then remove the exclusions of hadoop jars.

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
                <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
                <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
                <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Still Same error this is my new pom  :  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KfMbBawgKUtDo4Q_KeABAob9zCoCA84I

Comment: You need to make the link available to the public, I can't access it.

Comment: no you can access:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FZP-NDqyrM3JIx6tK_SUMdc6WAcohMqh

Comment: The dependency tree looks fine to me now. Not sure why you have storm-kafka set to provided scope though. Also you are targeting Java 1.5 with your compiler plugin, you should set it to 1.7 instead. Could you try building your project and verifying that the Hadoop class files are ending up in the jar you're uploading to Storm?

Comment: i have made both the changes,even i have set it 1.7,still same issue. now even in local mode i am getting security error

Comment: Yes, neither change will fix it, it was just something you should probably do regardless. Could you please build your jar and open it up and check that the Hadoop class files are in there? Also please verify that the Hadoop jars aren't present in your Storm lib directories, or at least that they are present in version 2.9.1.

Comment: this is the jar :https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xK0UGvs9Ku8PAaHIdqgeWgnFt4mdcSr9 
Everything  is fine.

Comment: Edited my answer, I think I found your problem

Comment: as you said ,I followed same steps .this is my new pom:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FZP-NDqyrM3JIx6tK_SUMdc6WAcohMqh

Comment: It works for me. The pom generates a jar containing the right version of hadoop-auth.

Comment: yeah even it contain right version of jars.but why is still show error.

Comment: I don't know. Do you have any hadoop jars in your extlib, extlib-daemon or lib directories in the Storm install folder?

Comment: no their are no jars in lib,exlib,exlib-daemon direcotries

Comment: Then I don't know.